# CakeBuild: DotNetCoreBuild vs DotNetBuild?

Tags: c#, cakebuild

What's the difference between DotNetCoreBuild vs DotNetBuild?

I used DotNetCoreBuild for my soluion. All projects in the solution are core projects. After adding a new not core project the build does not run anymore. The build endlose waits....

Is there another way to build mixed projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back when Cake first started in 2014, there was no dotnet cli, or dotnet core, or standard, or anything like that.  Instead, there was only MSBuild and XBuild.  The `DotNetBuild` aliases were added as a convenience alias, which would, based on whether you were running on Windows or Posix, either shell out to MSBuild or XBuild.  You can find information about this alias here:

https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools/DotNetBuildAliases/B154D87C

Then, when the dotnet cli came about, we added another set of aliases use `DotNetCore...` which are responsible for shelling out to the dotnet cli.  Information about these aliases can be found here:

https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.DotNetCore/DotNetCoreAliases/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what's about building mixed projects?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this should be possible using the dotnet cli, however, I would suggest that you first get this working directly using the dotnet cli, and then try to get it to build in Cake.  At the end of the day, Cake is a build automation tool, it is not going to magically know how to do things.  You will need to first get it working outside of Cake, and then do the same thing there.  If you need to build the projects seperately then that is definitely something Cake can help to automate, but again, you are going to need to figure that out.

Comment: MSBuild is now available on all .NET, Mono and .NET Core. When using .NET CLI it might be missing some targets though. You can provide targeting packs or framwork overrides to sort that though.